# normal distribution plus delta dirac distribution

Tags: probability, integration, dirac-delta

For the probability density function in the form:$$f_X(x)=0.5\delta(x+\mu)+0.5N(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
Find the differential entropy defined by $h(X)=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)\log f_X(x)dx$.

[Here is a plot of $f_X(x)$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl0ry.png)

**Question**

Is the follwing solution is valid?

$$h(X)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)\log(f_X(x))dx
\\=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}0.5\bigg[\delta(x+\mu)+N(\mu,\sigma^2)\bigg]\log(0.5\bigg[\delta(x+\mu)+N(\mu,\sigma^2)\bigg])
\\
\\=-0.5\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg[\delta(x+\mu)+N(\mu,\sigma^2)\bigg]\log(0.5)
\\-0.5\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x+\mu)\log\bigg[\delta(x+\mu)+N(\mu,\sigma^2)\bigg]
\\-0.5\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}N(\mu,\sigma^2)\log\bigg[\delta(x+\mu)+N(\mu,\sigma^2)\bigg]
\\=-\log(0.5)-0.5\log\bigg[1+N(\mu,\sigma^2)\bigg]_{x=-\mu}
\\-0.5N(\mu,\sigma^2)\log\bigg[1+N(\mu,\sigma^2)\bigg]_{x=-\mu}
\\-0.5\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}N(\mu,\sigma^2)\log\bigg[N(\mu,\sigma^2)\bigg]
\\+0.5N(\mu,\sigma^2)\log\bigg[N(\mu,\sigma^2)\bigg]_{x=-\mu}$$

Comment: $\ln\delta$ is an ill-defined quantity, so that the differential entropy of Dirac delta is usually set to $-\infty$ (because it contains no randomness and thus has the lowest entropy between among all distributions).

Comment: We have that $X\sim B\mu+(1-B)Y$ where $B\sim \textrm{Bernoulli}(0.5)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ are independent random variables. $X$ does not have a density, so OP's problem is ill-posed.

Comment: @Snoop Bernoulli law doesn't have a density, since it is discrete random variable; the continuous analog is precisely the Dirac delta distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got muddled up and mixed the random variables with their probability density functions. I guess that you should have a random variable $X \sim \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Delta}(-\mu) + \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, the entropy of which you would like to compute.

As Dirac delta distributions are deterministic in nature, it behaves as a constant and, in the present case, centers the adjacent normal law, i.e. $X \equiv \frac{1}{2}\left(-\mu+\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)\right) = \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2/4)$
whose entropy is simply given by $H[X] = H[\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2/4)] = \ln\sqrt{2\pi e} + \ln(\sigma^2/4)$.

Comment: Your deduction is false, as saying $X\equiv \frac{1}{2}(-\mu+\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2))$. Note that in this case, you will have $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, which has a quite different PDF that the one in the OP.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz OP's PDF doesn't make much sense, $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is a random variable and not a density function, leaving aside that the entropy of Dirac distribution is ill-defined, that is why I suspect an erroneous statement in the instructions.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Moreover, you can check that $\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Delta}(-\mu) + \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2) \sim \frac{1}{2}({N}(\mu,\sigma^2)-\mu)$, since they possess the same characteristic function. It is not surprising, since a Dirac variable is the way to translate a deterministic (i.e. non-random) quantity in the probability language; in other words, $X\sim\mathrm{Delta}(x_0)$ means that $X = x_0$ is a constant.

Comment: Your interpretation is wrong. OP's function is a valid description of a probability law. However, it is not a density. See also my comment on OP's post.

Comment: @Snoop I've never said his function cannot be a probability distribution, but this one won't have a meaningful entropy. Added to the fact that OP wrote $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, I suspect (but I'm not in his mind, he has to confirm) that he intended to give the definition of the random variable $X$ instead of its density function, which additionally gives a more reasonable result.

Comment: @AbezhikoThanks for your reply,

Comment: This distribution is the mixture of discrete and normal, which gives bimodal, and one special case is delta and normal